# SVG sprite file - is it necessary for it to have ".svg" extension, or is php/nothing ok so long as the content type header is set correctly?

Tags: php, svg

I have a PHP script that generates my SVG sprite on the fly.  Naturally that file ends in `.php`, not `.svg`.

I'm setting the Content-type at the top of the script with `header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');`

I have nginx set up in such a way that php extensions are optional, so I can now reference my svg icons with:

`<use href="/icons#svg-save-icon" xlink:href="/icons#svg-save-icon" x="0" y="0"></use>`

Is that ok?  It works in the browsers I've tested it in - I just don't know if I'm missing out on some browser optimisation because it can't "guess" as to the content-type before it retrieves the file.

As an aside, I also have these caching headers set up, does this look right for a year-long far future expiry?

```
header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000');
header_remove('Pragma');
header_remove('Set-Cookie');
header_remove('Expires');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
```

Comment: sure, browsers look at the mime-type and don't care about extensions.

Comment: That’s the difference between HTTP, and file system access. File suffixes have absolutely _zero_ meaning in HTTP - because there _are_ no “files” to begin with, only URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the `Content-Type` header is all that matters.

In general, browsers don't see URLs as breaking down into parts like "directory", "filename", and "extension"; in fact, HTTP has no concept of "files" at all. Rather, a URL is just a string to be sent to some server; the server then responds with some content, and a header indicating how that content should be interpreted.

Whether you reference your SVG as `/icons`, or `/icons.php`, or `/icons.awesome`, the browser will just send that URL, and have no idea if the response is coming from a file with that name, or a different name, or generated on demand.

You can see this in action on this very page: the URL doesn't end ".html", but the browser is rendering the HTML. That's not relying on some default built into the browser, it's because the `Content-Type` header that Stack Overflow's server sent identified the returned content as `text/html`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very familiar with dropping html/php extensions on HTML resources;  but wasn't sure if there might be hidden pitfalls with doing the same on image/etc resources.  I know it *works*, I just wanted to make sure that it doesn't cause a minor blip somehow, somewhere!